# how to pdf selected product id in laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

**i have view for product as shown in image i want to print barcode for selected product id or retrieve all if not selected any product**

[image]

**here is a code for checkbox in product index.view:-**

```
  <td> <input style="width:20px" type="checkbox" class="form-control select55" id="check-{{ $product->id }}" name="selected[]" value="{{ $product->id }}"></td>


 <script>
        $(".select55").on('click', function() {
            let productIdss = [];
            $("tbody input[type='checkbox']").each((index, input) => {
                if(input.checked) {
                    productIdss.push($(input).val());
                }
            })
            $(".input_productss").val(productIdss);
        });
 </script>
```

**here is a code for barcode request in product controller:-**

```
        if($request->has('barcode') && $request->barcode == 'true') {
            $mpdf = new Mpdf();
            $mpdf->autoScriptToLang = true;
            $mpdf->autoLangToFont = true;
        
            if($request->has('product_idss')) {
                // Create mpdf for selected product ID
                $productIds = explode(',', $request->input('product_idss'));
                $products = Product::whereIn('id', $productIds)->with('variants')->get();
                $currentLang = Language::where('regional','like', '%' . app()->getLocale() . '%')->first();
                Carbon::setLocale(app()->getLocale());
        
                foreach ($productIds as $productId) {
                    $product = $products->where('id', $productId)->first();
                    if($product) {
                        if($product->price_of_currency) {
                            $html = view('categories.products.barcodes', ['product' => $product,'rtl' => $currentLang->rtl, 'productIds' => $productIds])->render();
                            $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
                        } else {
                            if($product->variants && $product->variants->count() > 0) {
                                foreach ($product->variants as $variant) {
                                    $html = view('categories.products.barcodes', ['product' => $product,'rtl' => $currentLang->rtl, 'variant' => $variant, 'productIds' => $productIds])->render();
                                    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
                                }
                            } else {
                                $html = view('categories.products.barcodes', ['product' => $product,'rtl' => $currentLang->rtl, 'productIds' => $productIds])->render();
                                $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
                            }
                        }
                        $mpdf->AddPage();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // Create mpdf for all products
                $products = $products->with('variants')->get();
                $currentLang = Language::where('regional','like', '%' . app()->getLocale() . '%')->first();
                Carbon::setLocale(app()->getLocale());
        
                foreach ($products as $product) {
                    if($product->price_of_currency) {
                        $html = view('categories.products.barcodes', ['product' => $product,'rtl' => $currentLang->rtl])->render();
                        $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
                    } else {
                        if($product->variants && $product->variants->count() > 0) {
                            foreach ($product->variants as $variant) {
                                $html = view('categories.products.barcodes', ['product' => $product,'rtl' => $currentLang->rtl, 'variant' => $variant])->render();
                                $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
                            }
                        } else {
                            $html = view('categories.products.barcodes', ['product' => $product,'rtl' => $currentLang->rtl])->render();
                            $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
                        }
                    }
                    $mpdf->AddPage();
                }
            }
        
            $mpdf->Output('invoices/products_barcodes.pdf', \Mpdf\Output\Destination::FILE);
            return redirect()->to(asset('invoices/' . 'products_barcodes' . '.pdf'));
        }
```

**here is a code for html categories.products.barcodes.view in product controller:-**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>{{ $product->id }}</title>
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cairo&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <style>
            .invoice-box {
                width: 188.97637795px;
                height: 100%;
                padding: 20px 0;
                font-size: 16px;
                font-family: "Cairo", sans-serif;
            }

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="invoice-box @if($rtl) rtl @endif">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"  style="text-align: center">
                        <span>{{ $product->name . '-' . $product->sku }}</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        @if($variant)
                            <img style="width: 100%; height: 50px" src="{{ asset('products_barcodes/' . $variant->barcode) }}" alt="">
                        @else
                            <img style="width: 100%; height: 50px" src="{{ asset('products_barcodes/' . $product->barcode) }}" alt="">
                        @endif
                    </td>
                </tr>

                @if(isset($variant))
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2"  style="text-align: center">
                            <span>{{ $variant->variant . '-' . $variant->price->price_after_discount }}</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                @else
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2"  style="text-align: center">
                            <span>{{ $variant->variant . '-' . $products->price_of_currency->price_after_discount }}</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                @endif
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

when I select any of those product id and request to print barcodes it returns all product barcode

Comment: In the controller, if you dd($productIds) do you get the expected result ?

Comment: I don't think you'll have much luck setting the value of an HTML element to an array.